# Vimperator and Firefox JavaScript Debugger dont allow javascript code to be interpreted

Tags: firefox, javascript, vimperator

While using vimperator and having JavaScript Debugger on, if split view is toggled javascript code is not interpreted on enter, it add a new line.

Actually I have no idea on how it is possible to evaluate javascript on a split view while using vimperator. Pressing esc+shift should disable vimperator, but enter keeps on not evaluating javascript.

Comment: So you're entering code in the FF javascript command line at the bottom of the developer tools. It doesn't add new lines for me when used with Vimperator. The only way I can get multiple lines is by pasting in multiline code. Could it be another extension causing it? You could always try with Pentadactyl instead (you'd have to get the nightly from the web site: the version on addons.mozilla.org is always out-of-date)

Comment: @pyrocrasty thanks a lot for your response. In the meantime I've formatted the mac, and this issue stopped occurring. It might have been some extension conflict as you suggested, since ff is running with only 3 extensions now.